# How to add a new item to the Mesh submenu of the Add Menu in this script?

Tags: python, scripting

How do I include a new 'Realistic Stone' item in the Add menu, Mesh submenu in this script?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Realistic Stone",
    "author": "",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "VIEW3D > ADD > Mesh",
    "description": "Realistic Stone",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh"}

# Imports
import bpy
from bpy import context
import bmesh

class RealisticStoneStone(bpy.types.Operator):

    def execute(self, context):

        """Realistic Stone"""
        bl_idname = "mesh.realistic_stone_add"
        bl_label = "Realistic Stone"
        bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

        # Mesh - Create Cubic
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.00, 0.00, 1.00))
        bpy.context.object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        Cube = bpy.context.object
        Cube.name = 'RealisticStone'
        Object = Cube.name = 'RealisticStone'
        bpy.context.object.data.name = "RealisticStone"

        # Modifier - Multiresolution
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MULTIRES')
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Multires"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.5
        bpy.ops.texture.new()
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.001"].type = 'VORONOI'
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.001"].noise_scale = 1
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 2
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.25
        bpy.ops.texture.new()
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.002"].type = 'CLOUDS'
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.002"].noise_depth = 7
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace.001"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 3
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.01
        bpy.ops.texture.new()
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.003"].type = 'NOISE'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace.002"].show_expanded = False

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return self.execute(context)

def draw_item(self, context):
    self.layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
    self.layout.operator(RealisticStone.bl_idname, text="Realistic Stone", icon="PLUGIN")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(draw_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(draw_item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: Have you compared your script to the generic Add Mesh Object template script that ships with Blender? You might find your answer there.

Comment: Perhaps post the part that made it work as an answer for others that come here then. And you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Realistic Stone",
    "author": "",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "VIEW3D > ADD > Mesh > Add Realistic Stone",
    "description": "Realistic Stone",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh"}

# Imports
import bpy
from bpy import context
import bmesh

class RealisticStoneStone(bpy.types.Operator):

    """Realistic Stone"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.realistic_stone_add"
    bl_label = "Realistic Stone"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}


    def execute(self, context):

        # Mesh - Create Cubic
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.00, 0.00, 1.00))
        bpy.context.object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        Cube = bpy.context.object
        Cube.name = 'RealisticStone'
        Object = Cube.name = 'RealisticStone'
        bpy.context.object.data.name = "RealisticStone"

        # Modifier - Multiresolution
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MULTIRES')
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires")
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Multires"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.5
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.001"].type = 'VORONOI'
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.001"].noise_scale = 1
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 2
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.25
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.002"].type = 'CLOUDS'
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.002"].noise_depth = 7
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace.001"].show_expanded = False

        # Modifier - Displace 3
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.01
        bpy.data.textures["Texture.003"].type = 'NOISE'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Displace.002"].show_expanded = False

def invoke(self, context, event):
    return self.execute(context)

def draw_item(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("mesh.realistic_stone_add", icon="PLUGIN")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(draw_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(draw_item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```